# Talking to Adobe Acrobat from batch files

Tags: windows, pdf, batch-file, acrobat

I want to open a pdf file, then save it as a text and then close Acrobat.

I'd like to do it automatically from a command line so I can automate it. Is there any way to do it from a command line in Windows 7?

Comment: Doing it through Adobe (reader) via command line will be a little difficult, but I know there are some shareware programs that do pdf to text conversions and some have the ability to use command line arguments to do this.

Not gonna spend a couple hours looking into them for you so I commented instead of answered XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to write a script for the Windows Script Host or Powershell which would automate the process using the Adobe COM objects or (~~shudder~~) launching Acrobat Reader and controlling it using SendKeys.